# Pay 50% on benefits from US Social Security?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, social-security

I am not sure if it is like what it sounds, which is scary:

https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/013015/how-can-i-avoid-paying-taxes-my-social-security-income.asp

> From $25,000 to $34,000: You may have to pay income tax on up to 50%
> of your benefits.
>
> More than $34,000: Up to 85% of your benefits may be taxable.

So what does that mean?

1. If I get $24,999 of social security (filed as single), then there is no tax whatsoever
2. But if I get $25,001, then I "may have to pay income tax on up to 50% of [my] benefits"

So what does that mean? Up to 50% of $25,001 needs to be paid out, or that if I am at $34,000, which is max of the range, then half of that needs to be paid out?

I don't quite get it because it sounds so scary... first being taxed on the final money we get when we are at old age, and second, $25,000 per year is not a lot of money, especially in California in the San Francisco Bay Area. If my rent is $2000 per month for a one bedroom apartment, which is subpar, that means I can pay the rent and forget about eating.  Or else, if I move to another state or country, that means lifting my root and move to a place with all strangers when I become old?

But of that $25001 or $34000, is it true that I only pay tax on the amount that exceeds $25000. Meaning if it is $25,001, I really only need to pay tax on that $1, while if it is $34,000, then pay tax on $9000, but it probably falls into the 20% tax bracket for Federal and State tax combined?

Comment: The next to last paragraph is important but not specific to this tax. You need to plan out your budget based on your income and expenses, including taxes _regardless of how the tax is calculated_. Living in San Francisco doesn't exempt you from having to live within your means.

Comment: "Living in San Francisco doesn't exempt you from having to live within your means." this is just a smart way to say, "so you are lifted from the root to move somewhere else with strangers but so what? We don't care about you." US is so full of these forceful statements or actions

Comment: No one is forcing you to do anything - you are not _forced_ to retire. You have choices - you can cut your expenses or find additional income (a job). Yes it is expensive to live in certain areas, but that's why you should _plan_ for retirement, which doesn't mean just social security.

Comment: @DStanley right, everybody can work until they die

Comment: Whether you can live on your post-tax income is irrelevant to how much tax is due on that income. Please limit your question to that, not either you can continue to afford your pre-retirement home.

Comment: /either/whether/ in @chepner's comment (in case anyone else was having trouble figuring out the typo). Ah, auto-incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't say that you pay "a 50% tax" on your benefits, but that you pay tax on up to 50% *of* your benefits.

The amount of benefits would be taxable at your marginal rate, which would be much less than 50%.

So if your marginal rate was 20%, you might pay 20% tax on *up to 50%* of your benefits. Most likely it would be less than 50%, depending on other income and deductions.

That site also links to an IRS worksheet that you can use to calculate the tax due, but it has too variables to quickly generalize.

> But of that $25001 or $34000, is it true that I only pay tax on the amount that exceeds $25000.

Yes - most of these types of taxes are graduated, meaning that you don't suddenly jump tax rates on the entire amount, but that you are taxed on the amount over a certain threshold, or taxed different rates on different "levels" of income, so that the tax due increases gradually as income increased.

Comment: isn't it true that if it is $25,001, I only need to pay tax on that $1? (rather than tax on the 50% of the $25,001?) Otherwise, won't it be so unfair for a person who gets $24,999 and pay $0 tax, while for another person, who gets $25,001 and have to pay substantially more tax? (when their benefits differ only by $2)

Comment: and after sorting this out, I can decide to pay rent and forget about eating, or eat, and forget about living in an apartment and just live in the car

Comment: @StefanieGauss that is usually how taxes work, don't know about this particular tax. Yes, everything is expensive now - you can decide who to blame, whether it's the trillion dollar tax cuts and handouts to large corporations, or the $1200 everyone got one time.

Comment: You can also decide who to blame about your having to live on SS rather than also having savings.

Comment: If you're getting $25002, then $1 may be taxable, probably at a low percentage. That tax is unlikely to be enough to force a heat-or-eat decision, though that's not completely impossible. In which case you apply for additional assistance and/or get a job. Despite all the bad jokes about Walmart greeters, I know friends who have supplemented Social Security that way... and you may have the skills to land something that pays more. –

Comment: @StefanieGauss I tried to answer that in the last paragraph - yes only the amount _above_ the threshold would be taxable.

Comment: @DStanley so the line "From $25,000 to $34,000: You may have to pay income tax on up to 50% of your benefits." is not that accurate. It is more like "From $25,000 to $34,000: You may have to pay income tax on up to 50% of your benefits that exceeds $25,000."

Comment: @keshlam so if I have other savings and investment, I can at least eat some junk foods after the $2700 one bedroom apartment rent. It won't be that decent living and I have to worry about if I live too long, and the constant tax on your "oh your money was in after-tax 401k but it not in Roth 401k and now we can tax you". And my first company didn't really encourage us to save in 401k because when we don't save, they keep more money not needing to match... yeah, beautiful world just overall

Comment: I don't see how this tax is the problem - even if you had _no_ tax on any SS income, living in SF on $25k-$34k a year seems impossible.

Comment: @StefanieGauss what keeps you in the crazy expensive San Francisco? I'm sure you can find 1bd apartments for way less in Sacramento, Gilroy, or any other city 1-2 hours away. Let alone places like the central valley, northern California, or outside the state altogether.

Comment: @DStanley the tax only adds to the problem

Comment: @littleadv that's real good... get into old age, get kicked out by the city, and then worry that I'd live too long. That's just beautiful

Comment: @StefanieGauss that's the US for you, that's how it's always been. Why are you only discovering it now? In California, prop 13 would have protected you had you had your own place to live, but you didn't care for that I guess. Why are you complaining now?

Comment: I believe we've answered your question as posed: you were misunderstanding how much gets taxed, and misunderstanding tax rates on that amount. Possibly misunderstanding marginal tax rate as well. If you want to ask another question, you should start a new Question. If you want to say that you dislike taxes generally, that's not something Stack Exchange can give you an answer for.

Comment: @littleadv I would argue it's reality in general, not specific to the US - If you want to live in Paris or Stockholm or Mumbai but can't afford to, there's no magic solution to make that affordable.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that Social Security benefits are taxable income like any other income you get (from work, investments, pensions, etc.)

You will still have to file an annual tax return listing all your incomes including social security. However social security income is not as "bad" as other income since there is some tax protection.

Let's say you have $50,000 in social security benefits. Only a part of this is taxable. That would be

0%*$25000+50%*$9000 + 85%*16000 = $18100

This means your $50,000 of benefits generate $18100 of taxable income. How much taxes you pay on that depends a lot your other details (filing status, other income, deductions, etc.), but if that's you only source of income, the federal tax bill will be quite low.

Comment: Taking the OP's example of 20% tax rate, that would mean $3620 in tax. And I think that's worst case since the document quoted (which I admit I haven't dug into) is careful to say "may" and "up to." As always, ignore the scare headlines and read the published tax instructions to see what they actually say applies to your case. If you need help, some communities organize a free service  that helps the elderly figure out basic taxes. (And I admit that I'm starting to qualify as elderly at age sixty-mumble; that's nothing to be ashamed of!)

Comment: it is like, thank you for serving the society and now you can retired, and this is the retire money you can depend on when you are at old age... not easy to find work, and physically, you are less capable... not a lot of money, but maybe able to let you survive. OK, and we will tax you on this money, Jose.

Comment: How you feel about it isn't a topic for Stack Exchange. And in the American system there is no guarantee that you will actually be able to retire.

Comment: I suppose Stack Exchange may not be such a holistic place. It is more like a question with some standard answer and people move on with it.  It doesn't take human as a factor into it overall